# Post an a href value to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to send the id value of  tag to controller when user click on any link.

```
TempString1.Append("<li><a id="+aa[i].int_FeatureId+" href=../" + aa[i].Feature.vcr_LinkName + ">" + aa[i].Feature.vcr_FeaturesName + "</a></li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC you usually use `Html.ActionLink` or the like.

But to stay in your line, how about:

```
href=../" + aa[i].Feature.vcr_LinkName + "&featureId=" + aa[i].int_FeatureId + "
```

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string id, int featureId)
...
```